# d3js plot zoomed in a modal window on 'click'

Tags: d3.js

I used d3js to plot data from a csv file:

```
draw(filename, divID) {
  d3.csv(filename, function(data){
      ...
      .on('click', function(d){
           //open a modal and plot csv filename again
           draw_bigger(filename);   //call $("#mymodal").modal(); inside
```

The idea is that once the user clicks on the plot, a modal window pops out and re-plot the data with auto-range (more zoomed-in). Because of javascript closure, "filename" gets passed naturally to the inner `draw_bigger` function.

However the same file is requested twice from the server. I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Sure, the SVG generated by d3 is in the DOM. You can just apply a selector and copy the features you want (or the whole SVG content) and fill another SVG tag at the modal window - just like you would do with jQuery and ordinary HTML tags.

Comment: You can simply access the `data` object in the click handler.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you are correct. I missed that.